# Is there any other way to generate SHA1 key from android studio?

Tags: java, android, flutter, sha1

I am trying to run flutter project in Android Studio. I download the project and trying to get SHA 1 key for Firebase. How did I done that--> In android forlder --> open gradlew in Terminal --> run .\gradlew signingReport. I am getting error = Error: Missing keystore.

Here is the code

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Apps\News v3.0.5\App_Flutter_Code-3.0.5\android> .\gradlew signingReport
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: release
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :audio_session:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :connectivity_plus:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :device_info_plus:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :facebook_audience_network:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :file_picker:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_auth:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_core:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_dynamic_links:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :firebase_messaging:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_inappwebview:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_keyboard_visibility:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_local_notifications:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_login_facebook:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :flutter_tts:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :google_mobile_ads:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :google_sign_in_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :image_picker_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :in_app_review:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :just_audio:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :location:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :path_provider_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :permission_handler_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :share_plus:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :sign_in_with_apple:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :sms_autofill:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :sqflite:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :unity_ads_plugin:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :url_launcher_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :video_player_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :wakelock:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------

> Task :webview_flutter_android:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\DELL\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
33 actionable tasks: 33 executed
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Apps\News v3.0.5\App_Flutter_Code-3.0.5\android>
```

How dp I get SHA 1 key here?

I tried .\gradlew signingReport. But it gives me missing keystore error.

Comment: There is no code here. SHA1 is a secure hashing algorithm, not a key algorithm. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

open android directory in to the terminal then try `./gradlew signingReport` command.